# Python - write filename / filepath into a textfile

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I have some filenames defined in a Python script with tkinter who look like this:

```
def save_file(self):
self.filename = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename(title="Save...", filetypes=([("Excel Workbook","*.xlsx")]))
```

At the end the filename of these variables should be written out into a text file:

```
text_out = open('output.txt', 'w')
text_out.write("The first filename is " + self.filename + " + '\n')
text_out.write("The first pathname is " + self.filelocation + '\n')
text_out.close()
```

But it doesn't work. Has anyone any ideas? I have also tried it with:

```
text_out.write("The first filename is " + str(self.filename) + " + '\n')
```

but without the expedted result.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Does it write to the wrong file? Does it not write at all? Does it write the wrong thing? Do you get an error?

Comment: Please always include the error message, instead of just saying "it doesn't work". The message `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal` supplied by McClamrock instantly pointed out the error.

Comment: Hi @MisterMiyagi, thank you for you help. 
I have to explain more concerning the Python scripts error:
When typing:

    `text_out.write("The first filename is " + str(self.filename) + '\n')`
 
The result looks like this:
"The first filename is 47827544"

When I write it like this:

   ` text_out.write("The first filename is " + self.filename + '\n')`

I just get an error message from my try/except implementation

    `except:
            tkMessageBox.showinfo("Info", "Text couldnt be written")
            sys.exit(0)`

Answer (score -1):

I tried it from the command line and got this error message:

`SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`

This appears to mean that Python doesn't like having '\n' at the end of a bunch of strings stuck together with `+`. Try treating the items as a list and joining them, like this:

```
text_out = open('output.txt', 'w')
filewrite = ''.join([
    'The first filename is ', self.filename, '\n',
    'The first pathname is ', self.filelocation, '\n'])
text_out.write(filewrite)
text_out.close()
```

I got this idea from the *Python Cookbook,* and it works for me.

Comment: Python is perfectly fine with having `\n` at any position of a string. This also applies to any other special character, such as `\t`. The issue is, as the Exception says, a `SyntaxError` - meaning the definition of code is ill-formated, not its content.